# Duda lista anidada

Tags: python, base-de-datos, python-2.7, lista, estructuras-de-datos

```
                usuario = line_conten[1].split(":")[1]
                ip = IP
                puerto = line_conten[1].split(":")[-1]
                fecha = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", 
                                              time.localtime(time.time()))
                expires = line_conten[3].split(":")[-1]

                datosusuarios = [usuario, ip, puerto, fecha, expires]
                print(datosusuarios)
                listadatos = []
                *listadatos = listadatos.append(datosusuarios)*
                print(listadatos)
```

En la zona marcada es donde tengo la duda de que comando utilizar para añadir la lista "datosusuarios" dentro de la "listadatos". Actualmente utilizando el comando append me deja la lista vacia.

Comment: `.append()` es un método que directamente modifica la lista, pero no retorna nada. Si haces `listadatos.append(datosusuarios)`, se añadirá la información a la lista, pero ya que después _asignas_ `listadatos=` al resultado, y en realidad no hay resultado, "borras" (y pierdes) la lista ampliada. En definitiva, no reasignes el resultado. También podrías hacer `listadatos += [datosusuarios]` si prefieres esta sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos quiza podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
data = []
elemento1 = "Diego"
elemento2 = "28"
elemento3 = "test@gmail.com"
elemento4 = "1234567890"


elemento5 = "Fernanda"
elemento6 = "27"
elemento7 = "fer@gmail.com"
elemento8 = "9876543210"

element={}
element['nombre'] = elemento1
element['edad'] = elemento2
element['correo'] = elemento3
element['telefono'] = elemento4
data.append(element)
element['nombre'] = elemento5
element['edad'] = elemento6
element['correo'] = elemento7
element['telefono'] = elemento8
data.append(element)
print(data)
```

El resultado seria algo como esto:
[image: resultado]

Si te fijas **data** es el contenedor de todos mis valores, element1, element2..etc.. puede ser valores que vengan desde un array o valores sueltos(unitarios) como los de mi ejemplo si es en un array los metes en un ciclo for y agregas el metodo append como lo hago.

Espero te sirva de guia y ayude..!!